# Create an auto updating dropdown list - Google sheets

Tags: google-sheets

How can I create a dropdown list that sources the values in a different sheet but that at the same time when I put a new value into the validation cell, auto updates the values in the source sheet?

Thank you for your comments.

Answer (score 0):

### Solution

> To be able to do something like this

[image]

> First we need a pre filled list on "different sheet" and stack it with the range of values where the drop down list validation is, with **this formula**

```
=QUERY( {'source sheet'!A2:A ; A2:A }, "Select Col1 Where Col1 is not null")
```

[image]

> Next in source sheet range `A1:A` selected, Click Data and then Data validation > List from a range: Choose the cells that will be included in the list, from the "different sheet" range `B2:B`

> we should get a result like this

[image]